# Obtaining wi-fi connection status from Connection Manager

Tags: c++, authentication, visual-studio-2013, wifi

I have some code which successfully iterates over a list of wi-fi networks, and provides feedback about available networks. The essential calls shown here...

```
WlanOpenHandle(WLAN_API_VERSION, NULL, &dwVersion, &hSession);

PWLAN_INTERFACE_INFO_LIST pInterfaceInfoList = NULL;
WlanEnumInterfaces(hSession, NULL, &pInterfaceInfoList);

for(int i ...)
{
    PWLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_LIST pAvailableNetworkList = NULL;
    WlanGetAvailableNetworkList(hSession, &interfaceGUID,
           WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_INCLUDE_ALL_ADHOC_PROFILES |
           WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK_INCLUDE_ALL_MANUAL_HIDDEN_PROFILES,
           NULL, &pAvailableNetworkList);
    for(int j ...)
    {
        WLAN_AVAILABLE_NETWORK network = pAvailableNetworkList->Network[j];
        :
    }
}
```

This all works fine, and inside the inner loop I'm able to access all of the attributes that I need, such as signal strength, security flags, etc via the network data structure.

One thing that I am not able to obtain is information regarding connection status, such as AUTHENTICATING or AUTHENTICATION_FAILED, etc, so I have tried to introduce another call inside the loop as follows...

```
CM_CONNECTION_DETAILS connectionDetails;
memset(&connectionDetails, 0, sizeof(CM_CONNECTION_DETAILS));

connectionDetails.Version = CM_CURRENT_VERSION;
const char* ccp = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(network.dot11Ssid.ucSSID);
mbstowcs(connectionDetails.szName, &ccp[0], network.dot11Ssid.uSSIDLength);

DWORD dwCount = sizeof(CM_CONNECTION_DETAILS);

CM_RESULT cmr = CmGetConnectionDetailsByName(connectionDetails.szName, 
           &connectionDetails, &dwCount);

if (cmr == CMRE_SUCCESS)
{
    :
}
```

Upon calling the CmGetConnectionDetailsByName() function, the details inside the CM_CONNECTION_DETAILS structure look correct (name and version), but the function returns with CMRE_INVALID_CONNECTION and the structure is not populated.

I haven't been able to find any examples of this call being successful (only a couple of references to the call returning the same CMRE_INVALID_CONNECTION code).

Does anyone have any experience of using the call successfully, or alternatively suggest a better way to find out the connection status of a network (ie if AUTHENTICATION is in progress or if AUTHENTICATION failed, etc)?

[I'm using Visual Studio 2013 C++ (native Windows app, not MFC), the target is 32-bit and Unicode, running on Windows Compact 2013]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below doesn't quite give me the fine control that I was looking for, but it does at least give me the opportunity to find out the state a particular interface. This means that I can find out if the interface is currently in the process or authenticating, and depending whether the final state is connected or disconnected, I can find out if authentication was successful or not.

```
WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE getNetworkState(HANDLE hSession, GUID* pGUID, std::wstring& wsState, bool bReportState=true)
{
    WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE result = wlan_interface_state_not_ready;
    DWORD dwDataSize;
    void* pData;
    DWORD dwErrorCode = WlanQueryInterface(hSession, pGUID, wlan_intf_opcode_interface_state, NULL, &dwDataSize, &pData, NULL);
    if (dwErrorCode == ERROR_SUCCESS && pData != NULL)
    {
        WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE* pState = reinterpret_cast<WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE*>(pData);
        if (pState != NULL)
        {
            switch (*pState)
            {
            case wlan_interface_state_not_ready:                wsState = L"NOT_READY"; break;
            case wlan_interface_state_connected:                wsState = L"CONNECTED"; break;
            case wlan_interface_state_ad_hoc_network_formed:    wsState = L"AD_HOC_NETWORK_FORMED"; break;
            case wlan_interface_state_disconnecting:            wsState = L"DISCONNECTING"; break;
            case wlan_interface_state_disconnected:             wsState = L"DISCONNECTED";  break;
            case wlan_interface_state_associating:              wsState = L"ASSOCIATING";   break;
            case wlan_interface_state_discovering:              wsState = L"DISCOVERING";   break;
            case wlan_interface_state_authenticating:           wsState = L"AUTHENTICATING";    break;
            }
            result = *pState;
        }
        WlanFreeMemory(pData);
    }
    return result;
}
```

A limitation of this check, is that it doesn't readily support multiple connections on the same interface, This query doesn't allow us to query to which of the connections the status refers.

If I arrive at a better solution, I will report it here.